# How to add custom color scheme for syntax highlighting in a Text Editor using gtk source view and XML

Tags: xml, gtk, gtksourceview

I had built a text editor using **gtk** . It is a very simple text editor. I want to add syntax highlighting using **gtk source view** (probably). I want to use a custom style sheet in **XML** file format which I made for this text editor. How can I add syntax highlighting to my text editor ? And want to use my **custom color scheme**. And where to put that **XML** file ? Please any suggestions !